# How do I create a new angular app with ng command using yarn offline flag?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, yarnpkg

I am trying to create a new angular app while offline by running the following command with yarn as my default package manager

```
ng new my-app
```

The app boilerplate is created but when installing packages using yarn. Yarn keeps throwing an error saying I am offline, which I am, but I want the yarn to use the offline cache for angular to create the new app.
I have tried running:

```
ng new my-app --offline
```

But angular CLI does not recognize the offline flag.
npm used to work fine while I was offline, how do I get this working with yarn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the application with `--skip-install` to avoid install and use `npm install --offline` if you are using npm version greater than v5.0.0:

```
ng new test-app --skip-install
cd test-app
npm install --offline
```

It does error out if the package you want is not in the cache.

Comment: Thank you so much. The --skip-install flag worked. --offline tag in yarn wasn't working so I had to clear the cache and install everything fresh to get new packages to the cache. Appreciate the help.